# Event from dynamic ItemTemplate not caught

Tags: asp.net, formview, itemtemplate, itemcommand

I implemented a new dynamic ItemTemplate like this :

```
private sealed class CustomItemTemplate : ITemplate
{
    public CustomItemTemplate()
    {}

    void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        Table ItemTable = new Table();
        ItemTable.CssClass = "tablewidth";

        TableRow btnRow = new TableRow();
        ItemTable.Rows.Add(btnRow);

        TableCell btnCell = new TableCell();
        btnCell.CssClass = "bgcolorBlueLight";
        btnCell.ColumnSpan = 2;

        btnRow.Cells.Add(btnCell);

        ImageButton ImgBtnfvPrincipalInsertMode = new ImageButton();
        ImgBtnfvPrincipalInsertMode.CausesValidation = false;
        ImgBtnfvPrincipalInsertMode.ImageUrl = "~/Images/icon_insert_16.gif";
        ImgBtnfvPrincipalInsertMode.CommandName = "New";

        ImageButton ImgBtnfvPrincipalUpdateMode = new ImageButton();
        ImgBtnfvPrincipalUpdateMode.CausesValidation = false;
        ImgBtnfvPrincipalUpdateMode.ImageUrl = "~/Images/icon_edit_16.gif";
        ImgBtnfvPrincipalUpdateMode.CommandName = "Edit";

        btnCell.Controls.Add(ImgBtnfvPrincipalInsertMode);
        btnCell.Controls.Add(ImgBtnfvPrincipalUpdateMode);

        container.Controls.Add(ItemTable);
    }
  }
```

It contains two buttons, the first one opening the Insert mode and the second one opening the update mode. They show up with no problem.

My goal is to use it in a formview :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   formView1.ItemTemplate = new CustomItemTemplate();
}
```

And I'd like to catch commands from the two buttons :

```
protected void formView1_ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ITEM COMMANDNAME : " + e.CommandName);
}
```

Unfortunately, formView1_ItemCommand won't display anything when I click on my buttons

Yet, if I declare ItemTemplate classicaly :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ProspectsCustomFormView.ascx.cs" Inherits="controls_ProspectsCustomFormView" %>

<asp:FormView ID="formView1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="formView1_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Table ID="ItemTable" runat="server" CssClass="tablewidth">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell  CssClass="bgcolorBlueLight" ColumnSpan="2">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtnfvPrincipalInsertMode" runat="server" CommandName="New" CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon_insert_16.gif" ToolTip="New"/>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtnfvPrincipalUpdateMode" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon_edit_16.gif" ToolTip="Edit" />
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:FormView>
```

Then it works...

Which solution do you suggest ?

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention the formView is actually wrapped inside a User Control :

```
public partial class controls_CustomFormView : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       fv.ItemTemplate = new CustomItemTemplate();
    }

    private sealed class CustomItemTemplate : ITemplate
    {...}

}
```

Comment: it works here, are you sure the ItemCommand is binded? The event should bubble by default...

Comment: Luizgrs : what do you mean by "ItemCommand is binded" ?

Comment: Do you see something like this in your aspx? <asp:FormView runat="server" ID="formView1" *onitemcommand="formView1_ItemCommand"* 
        onmodechanging="formView1_ModeChanging">

Comment: Yes I have onitemcommand="formView1_ItemCommand", otherwise it wouldn't trigger when I declare classicaly

Comment: Your issue seems to be in somewhere else, I have even create a test site here with only your code, and it works by default...

Comment: Noticed your `UserControl` addition.  How are you instantiating the UserControl - declaratively, or in code?  For that matter, are you declaring the `FormView` in the `UserControl` markup, or creating it in code?

Comment: @Ann L. : FormView is declared in aspx and User control instantiated declaratively

Comment: The only other thing I can think of (which I mentioned in one of the edits to my answer) is to make sure that any control you create dynamically has its ID property explicitly set.  And, of course, that all of this (user control and all) is inside the Form on your web page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little outside my experience, but I note you don't  show your buttons raising events within your template.  You don't appear to be handling the events raised by the button commands.

There's nothing that I see to make the buttons cause the template object they live in to raise its `ItemCommand` event.

Like I said, this is a bit outside my experience, so maybe that's supposed to auto-wire itself.  But I'd try handling the buttons' `Command` event and having them raise the `ItemCommand` of the template.

ETA:  Having done some reading, I think Luizgrs is right and you shouldn't need to do special event handling.

I'm wondering now if the problem is that you are not adding any of your controls to `container.Controls` until the very end.  By doing it that way, you're relying on the `Add` method of `container.Controls` to go through the control hierarchy of the `Table` and hook up all the Command events with `BubbleEvent`.

Just as an experiment, try moving this line:

```
 container.Controls.Add(ItemTable);
```

... right to the top, like this:

```
 Table ItemTable = new Table();
 ItemTable.CssClass = "tablewidth";
 container.Controls.Add(ItemTable);
```

The difference would be that all your control additions would now be to controls already inside `container.Controls`.

ETA:  ALSO!  You need to assign an ID to the buttons!

```
    ImageButton ImgBtnfvPrincipalInsertMode = new ImageButton();
    ImgBtnfvPrincipalInsertMode.ID = "ImgBtnfvPrincipalInsertMode";
    ImgBtnfvPrincipalInsertMode.CausesValidation = false;
    ImgBtnfvPrincipalInsertMode.ImageUrl = "~/Images/icon_insert_16.gif";
    ImgBtnfvPrincipalInsertMode.CommandName = "New";
```

Comment: Commands events in ASP.NET bubbles through the hierarchy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Ann L. so you suggest to handle events inside instantiatein ? Could you provide an example ?

Comment: @Luizgrs  Having done some reading, I think you're right.  I have amended my answer with a different idea.

Comment: @codablank1  Having done some reading, I think Luizgrs is right.  I have amended my answer with a different suggestion.

Comment: @codablank1  One more suggestion.  I think this is the key difference between what you were doing declaratively and programmatically.

Comment: @Ann L. Tried your last solutions, but still doesn't do it; I really wonder what differs in my code from Luizgrs'